# how to change button color of that which is tapped in flutter using ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, button, background-color

I have created buttons using `ListView.builder`, now i want if i tapped on any button than only that button color should change, but when i tap on any button all buttons color are changing.

here is the code

```
List<String> litems = ["Counter No 1", "Counter No 2", "Counter No 3", "Counter No 4"];
bool pressAttention=false;

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: litems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 55.0,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
                              child: new RaisedButton(
                              child: new Text(litems[index]),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              ),
                              color: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                              onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention), 
                      ),

                      
                            ),
                            SizedBox20(),
                          ],
                        );
                        
                      }),
                      
                  ),
);
  }
}
```

please help if any one know how to do this.

Comment: Try adding `key: Key(index.toString())` at your `Container` to see if it works.

Comment: change the color line to this => color: pressAttention == index   ?  Colors.green   :   Colors.grey.white,

Comment: @esentis it is not working bro!

Comment: Try @AwiasRehman solution !

Comment: @AwiasRehman ```pressAttention``` has bool type, plus it is not working it says this ```Equality operator `==` invocation with references of unrelated types```

Comment: set to this then check   int pressAttention = 1000;

Comment: You need one more variable, `selectedIndex` and check against it.

Comment: try int selectedIndex =-1; 
onPressed() =>setState(() => selectedIndex = index);
 color: index == selectedIndex ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375743/flutter-dart-how-to-select-specific-card-in-in-listview-and-toggle-an-icon-co/69375980#69375980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to extract the button logic in a separate widget. However this will not work if you need every `pressAttentions` values in the top widget.

Anyway, here is the simplest way:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Material(child: MyApp())));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> litems = ["Counter No 1", "Counter No 2", "Counter No 3", "Counter No 4"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: litems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return MyButton(title: litems[index]);
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyButton> createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  // Default to non pressed
  bool pressAttention = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 55.0,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
        child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text(widget.title),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
          color: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
          onPressed: () => setState(() => pressAttention = !pressAttention),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the way if you need to have the list of `pressAttentions`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Material(child: MyApp())));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> litems = ["Counter No 1", "Counter No 2", "Counter No 3", "Counter No 4"];

  // Initialize with the same length as litems and with only falses
  late List<bool> pressedAttentions = litems.map((e) => false).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: litems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final pressAttention = pressedAttentions[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 55.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              child: new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text(litems[index]),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                color: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: () => setState(() => pressedAttentions[index] = !pressAttention),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As a bonus, here is if you want only 1 button at a time only to be selected:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Material(child: MyApp())));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> litems = ["Counter No 1", "Counter No 2", "Counter No 3", "Counter No 4"];

  // Initialize to -1 so that none are selected
  // If you want to select the first by default you could change this to 0
  int pressedAttentionIndex  = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: litems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final pressAttention = pressedAttentionIndex == index;

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 55.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              child: new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text(litems[index]),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                ),
                color: pressAttention ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                onPressed: () => setState(() => pressedAttentionIndex = index),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As a side note: You seem to have issues with your naming:

- DO you camelCase to name attributes (BAD: `litems`, GOOD: `lItems`)
- DO start your bool variables be `is` or `has`: (BAD: `pressAttention`, GOOD: `hasPressedAttention`)

Comment: thank you so much, will follow your guides.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you and one thing used **ElevatedButton** instead of **RaisedButton**  because current flutter version RaisedButton Widget is depricated. [ElevatedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

Declare int var and your list:

```
int? tappedIndex; 

  List<String> litems = [
    "Counter No 1",
    "Counter No 2",
    "Counter No 3",
    "Counter No 4"
  ];
```

Declare initState() method

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tappedIndex = 0;
  }
```

Your Widget:

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: litems.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    ),
                    primary: tappedIndex == index
                        ? Colors.blue
                        : Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(litems[index]),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      tappedIndex = index;
                    });
                  }),
            );
          }),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Full Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Search(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  const Search({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Search> createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  int? tappedIndex;
  List<String> litems = [
    "Counter No 1",
    "Counter No 2",
    "Counter No 3",
    "Counter No 4"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tappedIndex = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: litems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        primary: tappedIndex == index
                            ? Colors.blue
                            : Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(litems[index]),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          tappedIndex = index;
                        });
                      }),
                );
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your Result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

using type int to mark tapped button,

```
List<String> litems = ["Counter No 1", "Counter No 2", "Counter No 3", "Counter No 4"];

late int tapIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tapIndex = litems.length; // make sure no buttons are clicked in the initial state
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                SizedBox(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: litems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 55.0,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.9,
                              child: new RaisedButton(
                              child: new Text(litems[index]),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              ),
                              color: tapIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                              onPressed: () => setState(() => tapIndex = index), 
                      ),

                      
                            ),
                            SizedBox20(),
                          ],
                        );
                        
                      }),
                      
                  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).